How to make curves on the sides at the bottom of a section
On different sections I have curves at the bottom like the ones in the picture. The picture now shows a section of the main banner. border-radius makes the rounding too steep, I need it more smoothly. And I can’t make a negative rounding of the right side. How can I create this effect using CSS?



.hero-section {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background: red;
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 82.5%, 1.69492% 84.3293%, 3.38983% 86.1385%, 5.08475% 87.9078%, 6.77966% 89.6179%, 8.47458% 91.25%, 10.1695% 92.7862%, 11.8644% 94.2098%, 13.5593% 95.505%, 15.2542% 96.6578%, 16.9492% 97.6555%, 18.6441% 98.487%, 20.339% 99.1435%, 22.0339% 99.6176%, 23.7288% 99.9041%, 25.4237% 100%, 27.1186% 99.9041%, 28.8136% 99.6176%, 30.5085% 99.1435%, 32.2034% 98.487%, 33.8983% 97.6555%, 35.5932% 96.6578%, 37.2881% 95.505%, 38.9831% 94.2098%, 40.678% 92.7862%, 42.3729% 91.25%, 44.0678% 89.6179%, 45.7627% 87.9078%, 47.4576% 86.1385%, 49.1525% 84.3293%, 50.8475% 82.5%, 52.5424% 80.6708%, 54.2373% 78.8616%, 55.9322% 77.0922%, 57.6271% 75.3821%, 59.322% 73.75%, 61.017% 72.2138%, 62.7119% 70.7902%, 64.4068% 69.495%, 66.1017% 68.3422%, 67.7966% 67.3446%, 69.4915% 66.513%, 71.1864% 65.8565%, 72.8814% 65.3824%, 74.5763% 65.0959%, 76.2712% 65%, 77.9661% 65.0959%, 79.661% 65.3824%, 81.3559% 65.8565%, 83.0509% 66.513%, 84.7458% 67.3446%, 86.4407% 68.3422%, 88.1356% 69.495%, 89.8305% 70.7902%, 91.5254% 72.2138%, 93.2203% 73.75%, 94.9153% 75.3821%, 96.6102% 77.0922%, 98.3051% 78.8616%, 100% 80.6708%, 100% 0%);
    shape-outside: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 82.5%, 1.69492% 84.3293%, 3.38983% 86.1385%, 5.08475% 87.9078%, 6.77966% 89.6179%, 8.47458% 91.25%, 10.1695% 92.7862%, 11.8644% 94.2098%, 13.5593% 95.505%, 15.2542% 96.6578%, 16.9492% 97.6555%, 18.6441% 98.487%, 20.339% 99.1435%, 22.0339% 99.6176%, 23.7288% 99.9041%, 25.4237% 100%, 27.1186% 99.9041%, 28.8136% 99.6176%, 30.5085% 99.1435%, 32.2034% 98.487%, 33.8983% 97.6555%, 35.5932% 96.6578%, 37.2881% 95.505%, 38.9831% 94.2098%, 40.678% 92.7862%, 42.3729% 91.25%, 44.0678% 89.6179%, 45.7627% 87.9078%, 47.4576% 86.1385%, 49.1525% 84.3293%, 50.8475% 82.5%, 52.5424% 80.6708%, 54.2373% 78.8616%, 55.9322% 77.0922%, 57.6271% 75.3821%, 59.322% 73.75%, 61.017% 72.2138%, 62.7119% 70.7902%, 64.4068% 69.495%, 66.1017% 68.3422%, 67.7966% 67.3446%, 69.4915% 66.513%, 71.1864% 65.8565%, 72.8814% 65.3824%, 74.5763% 65.0959%, 76.2712% 65%, 77.9661% 65.0959%, 79.661% 65.3824%, 81.3559% 65.8565%, 83.0509% 66.513%, 84.7458% 67.3446%, 86.4407% 68.3422%, 88.1356% 69.495%, 89.8305% 70.7902%, 91.5254% 72.2138%, 93.2203% 73.75%, 94.9153% 75.3821%, 96.6102% 77.0922%, 98.3051% 78.8616%, 100% 80.6708%, 100% 0%);
}
<div class="hero-section"></div>



I found similar examples, but I can’t make it look like in the screenshot, so that only on the sides there are waves like this

clip-path would be worth a try. If you could provide us a minimal reproducible example of the code you used.

@DarkBee your example of a similar question uses svg for this. And I would like (if possible) to use clip path to create the section shape. svg doesn't suit me much

There are several answers in there which actually use clip-path...

@MrJoky gave an example of a clip path that I found, but I can’t adjust it to the look as in the screenshot

Here comes math into it or trial and error. Change the number and test around what fits the best. There are some pages on the internet which provide a clip-path generator. Maybe they come in handy.

Polygons don't have curves... you need a path.
